# Azure media service get the thumbnail file URL

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, video-thumbnails

We currently are uploading video using Azure media services.  When the job runs in Media Service it creates a thumbnail.  I can navigate to it from the Azure Portal.

When the job finishes, we use event grid and have code which handles the event.  We receive in a JSONObject which has the following form

```
outputs {[
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.JobOutputAsset",
    "assetName": "output-06982218-ecb1-4680-8cd4-c6800d991fba",
    "error": null,
    "label": "BuiltInStandardEncoderPreset_0",
    "progress": 100,
    "state": "Finished"
  }
]}
```

If I navigate to that output Asset in Azure portal, it shows

Storage container:asset-a5536b5c-3024-4162-ad78-81f5448d3f68

and inside this is the thumb nail file

My questions is given the output-06982218-ecb1-4680-8cd4-c6800d991fba

how can I general a URL to
asset-a5536b5c-3024-4162-ad78-81f5448d3f68/Thumbnail000001.jpg
which is the thumbnail file?

We want to store this in a database for use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Asset in AMS has a container name property on it.

You can use that to find the container that stores your contents for the asset including the MP4 files, manifests, metadata, and any output thumbnail JPG or PNG or VTT files.
To get access to that, just use the Storage Client SDKs. We have many samples of downloading content using storage client SDKs in our sample repos.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/assets/get#asset

Check out the Node/Typescript ones for various examples of using the Storage client SDKS to download content.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/main/VideoEncoding/Encoding_Sprite_Thumbnail

If you need to just get a URL to that file, you can also create a SAS URL on the Asset using the GetContainerSAS method and then append the name of the file you want to that SAS URL and download it directly using the URL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/assets/list-container-sas
Just note that GetContainerSAS will give you a SAS URL to the container. You still have to use some URL Path library to append the name of your .jpg or .png image to the end of that URL, but preserve the query string with the token on it.

UPDATE: I also created a quick Typescript/Node.js sample to show how to create an Asset with your own container name, and how to get it back.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Assets/get-container-from-asset.ts

UPDATE 2:  Added another sample for .NET here - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/blob/main/Assets/Program.cs

Comment: Ok, but this issue I have is how do I get the container name. In this case it is asset-a5536b5c-3024-4162-ad78-81f5448d3f68.  The event grid is giving me the output-06982218-ecb1-4680-8cd4-c6800d991fba.  I do not know how to get the container name (asset-a5536b5c-3024-4162-ad78-81f5448d3f68) from the given output-06982218-ecb1-4680-8cd4-c6800d991fba

Comment: I assume that "output-guid" is the name of your asset, as that is familiar format from samples.  If you do a GET on that asset name, check the properties for the containerName.  We default to create container names with asset-guid format, but you can also define your own container name on creation of an asset. 
See this sample in Typescript/node.js here - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Assets/get-container-from-asset.ts

Comment: You are correct that output-guid is the name of the asset.  When you say do a GET I assume you mean using the REST API to do an HTTP GET, but that is not what we are looking to do.  We want to get the container name in the C# processing code.  SO we need an SDK way to get the container name.  When we do a client.Assets.GetAsync call, the there is no properties, and no container name

Comment: No, I dont mean use REST API... since all SDK's are just autogenerated from the REST API using AutoRest, you can use any of the SDKs to make an equivalent GET call on the assets resource collection. In the .NET version of the SDK it is called asset.Container
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.models.asset.container?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-management-media-models-asset-container

Comment: When creating an Asset or getting one back in .NET you will be getting back an Asset object.    This is the default settings on the Asset object. 
Asset.Asset(string id = null, string name = null, string type = null, Guid assetId = default(Guid), DateTime created = default(DateTime), DateTime lastModified = default(DateTime), string alternateId = null, string description = null, string container = null, string storageAccountName = null, AssetStorageEncryptionFormat storageEncryptionFormat = default(AssetStorageEncryptionFormat), SystemData systemData = null)

Comment: Try this sample also https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/blob/main/Assets/Program.cs

Comment: Using the Asset.Get worked.  I was able to use this asset to generate a BlobSAS.  I tried to up vote, but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to be allowed to up vote.  Thanks for your help